# @Around in Spring Boot AOP combination of @After, @Before, @AfterReturning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

Can we say the @Around annotation in spring boot AOP is a combination of @Before and @After method.

```
@Around("myPointCut()")
public Object applicationLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint){
    logger.info(" for the Method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() +
                    " Request received : {}", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    Object res = null;
    try {
        res = joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.info(" for the Method :"+ joinPoint.getSignature().getName() +
                        " Response received : {}", res);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

With this advice method annotated with @Around annotation, we can get the input parameters and also the returned object with proceed() which creates a proxy demo class and calls the actual implemented method.
If let's say we don't have @Around annotation, then we would have to use the @Before and @After annotations and two separate methods to achieve the input and output parameters.

So can we say just @Around annotation is enough and we don't require @Before, @After, @AfterReturning annotations as these are all catered by @Around.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Basically for a method that has multiple `@Before` , `@After` , `@AfterReturing` and `@AfterThrowing` advices applied on it can be converted to a single `@Around` advice.

The main difference is that `@Around` is a more generic advice type which gives you the most flexibility. You have total control on how to apply advices on a method invocation while the other more specific advice types provide you a declarative approach for doing such thing (e.g. use `@Order` to define execution order). So it is just a matter if you like to do it in a imperative (i.e `@Around`) or declarative way.

And the spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-api-advice-types) also has some comments about how to choose between them. I modify them slightly based on the context of your question as follows :

> `@Around` offer interoperability with other AOP Alliance-compliant AOP
> implementations. The other more specific advice type implement common
> AOP concepts but in a Spring-specific way. While there is an advantage
> in using the most specific advice type, stick with `@Around` advice if
> you are likely to want to run the aspect in another AOP framework.

> The main advantage of the more specific advice is that there is no
> need to invoke the `proceed()` method and, therefore, no possibility of
> inadvertently failing to proceed down the interceptor chain.

Comment: So that means if someone is using @Around, then it won’t be compatible with generic interceptors and filters which is the starting point for any spring boot application. Does this proceed() come in between

Comment: no . those things you mentioned are not implemented based on AOP technology. So they are nothing to do with `@Around`

Comment: here you have mentioned interceptor chain, can you please elaborate how this is different from interceptors in spring boot.

Comment: actually what interceptors in spring boot do you mean ? I assume you mention is `HandlerInterceptor`. If yes and if you are interested , please look at their source codes respectively to get the ideas and you will find they are different things. The entry pointer for you to understand the AOP stuff is `JdkDynamicAopProxy` , it is based on the `InvocationHandler` stuff at the most raw level while the `HandlerInterceptor` does not involve any `InvocationHandler`

Comment: Ok, So basically you are mentioning that there are two ways in which proxy strategy can be done. One is JdkDynamicAopProxy in which a proxy class uses an interface, and Other is CGLIB in which proxy class uses implementation class. Is the understanding correct.

Comment: Sorry . this is not what i mean. And i actually don't understand what is your question. For example, what is the generic interceptors and filter in spring boot do you refer to ? Can you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: I was referring to the interceptor wherein your request comes there first before going to the controller and you can take headers values from your request and do other stuff. I got your point that they are not part of Spring boot aop. In the above comment I was just rephrasing that the @Advice uses any of the two proxy strategies. One you have mentioned JdkDynamicAopProxy and other I was mentioning CGLIB.

Comment: Ok , then we are on the same page now . And your understanding is wrong, `HandlerInterceptor` is nothing do with with AOP (i.e JdkDynamicAopProxy) or those  CGLIB stuff you mentioned .It is just a 'plain' java call. No AOP magic involved in it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistakes and making responses understandable.

Comment: Ok . Thanks for making your question understandable too

Comment: your profile looks impressive 